# Cómo crear una API y meter la info directamente en MongoDB

Tags: python, api, mongodb

Estoy creando una API y quiero meter los datos directamente a MongoDB,estoy usando flask y python para crear la API.cuando intento hacer una petición a la API no parece funcionar,este es mi código:

````
friends_personaje= {'name':['Rachel','Monica','Joey','Chandler','Ross','Phoebe'],
'familyname':['Green','Geller','Tribbiani','Bing','Geller','Buffay']}


from src.controllers.queries import *
from app import *
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')

db = client.friends

db.createCollection("Friends")

x = "Friends".insert_one(friends_personaje)```
````

Answer (score 0):

La función `createCollection` no existe, pero sí `create_collection`. Prueba cambiando la penúltima línea por ésta:

```py
db.create_collection("Friends")
```